# DNSに登録してあるサブドメインを取得する方法

Tags: bash, unix, dns

DNSに登録されているサブドメインをすべて取得することは可能でしょうか。

```
$ command example.com
    => example.com A 111.111.111.111
    => hoge.example.com A 111.111.111.111
    => huga.example.com A 111.111.111.111
```

このようなものを期待しています。

Comment: この様なサイト [Find Subdomains :: Online Penetration Testing Tools](https://pentest-tools.com/information-gathering/find-subdomains-of-domain) があります。ただ、使ってみればお分かりかと思いますが、自動化は難しいかと思います。ご参考まで。

Comment: Security.SEにも [How can I find subdomains of a site?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/35078) という質問がありますが、やはりゾーン転送ぐらいのようです。辞書攻撃のできるツールはあるようですが。

Answer (score 3):

DNS コンテンツサーバーに登録されているすべてのレコードを得るには、ゾーン転送が許可されている必要があります。一般的には、アクセス元の IP アドレスをもとに許可します。許可されていなければ取得は不可能です。

許可されているなら ISC BIND の `host`(1) コマンドでゾーン転送することで可能です。ドメインのサブドメインが別の NS に委任されている場合は、別途委任先の NS にも問い合わせる必要があります。

```
$ host -t axfr example.com ns.example.com
```